# Invalidating old software licensed with RLM

Tags: c++, c++17, compatibility, licensing, backwards-compatibility

#### Scenario

Customers have received a software package with a time limited RLM license. The license is about to expire and an update is planned, *i.e.* a new package is to be delivered soon.

Over the last months, several defects were discovered in the software and we need to prevent customers from being able to use the old software package in combination with a license that is delivered with the new software package.

Some further context: The software is written in C++, this is also how the RLM library is accessed.

#### RLM structure

An RLM license is structured as follows:

```
LICENSE some_isv some_product 1.0 10-jan-2020 uncounted hostid=ANY
```

From what I understand reading the documentation, licenses provide downward compatibility, *i.e.* a version `1.1` is compatible with a version `1.0`, but not vice versa. However in our case this is not helpful, because a valid RLM license of version *e.g.* `1.1` can be copied to replace the license of version *e.g.* `1.0` which results in a functioning old software package.

The software version is provided to `checkOutLicense` by the software itself, be it via key management system, hardcoded string or anything else.

#### Question

How can a new software package be delivered, so that the new package does not provide an RLM license that is backwards compatible?

Obviously a package could be delivered, so that the new package carries version `0.99` and so does the license. However there are several gripes with this:

- It does not comply with actual software versioning, as the software packages are versioned in a relatively common fashion in ascending order.
- Now, instead of new licenses being compatible with old products, but not vice versa, the old licenses would be compatible with new products, but not vice versa.
- This defeats the point of the RLM downward compatibility. If at some point in the future a package for version `1.3` is to be delivered, then this leads to a choice: Either the new package can be activated with an old license, or the new package is only active with a newest license, but then this license is also valid for all old packages.

Basically the problem seems to lie in backward compatibility. I an looking to introduce a 1-to-1 relationship between license version and software version.

#### TL;DR

How to deliver a new software package using RLM licenses, so that the new license is only valid for exactly the desired software version?

Comment: If you want to break all forwards/backwards compatibility, what happens if you change `some_product` string? Reprise/RLM can probably provide something more specific though, looks like something I would definitely expect to come with a full support package.

Comment: Have you tried to contact RLM directly with this question ? after all it's a proprietary product and they should be interested in helping you.

Comment: This is my next step, I suppose. Currently I am digging through documentation and my question is intended to find out if there is some knowledge I missed. I think the `product` tag might be the solution I am looking for, not sure yet.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming? Maybe it would be more suitable on Software Development?